# Sort list on priority, then reverse order of elements with the same priority

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a list on prioriy high to low. This works correctly, but what i need is that elements that have the same priority are reversed (because i need the last added items first). the name variable is something that i added to quickly see the original order

Some code to clarify:

```
 myList.add(new Test(-1,"first"));
 myList.add(new Test(-1,"second"));
 myList.add(new Test(-1,"third"));
 myList.add(new Test(1, "fourth"));
 myList.add(new Test(1, "fifth"));

 public static class Test{
    private int priority;
    private String name;

    public Test(int priority, String name) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now i do this:

> myList = Stream.of(myList).sortBy(r -> -r.priority).toList();

And the result is:

> fourth, fifth, first, second, third

the result i would like to have instead:

> fifth, fourth, third, second, first

How can i do something like this (Preferrably using the https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  myList.stream().sorted((t1,t2) ->{
          if (t1.priority == t2.priority)
              return -1;
          return -(Integer.compare(t1.priority, t2.priority));
      }).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You could try like this

EDIT: I fixed some stuff in the solution, you should try it rn

Comment: i don't need to compare anything by name. I just want the elements sorted based on priority, and sort elements with the same priority based on when they were added in the original list (but in reverse order)

Comment: in that case, you can just replace t2.name.compareTo(t1.name) to "return 1", in that case it should put t2 before t1

Comment: @PrisonMike I've made some changes to the code, I had some problems with it, now it should be working

Comment: A little bit clearer: `myList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(t -> t.priority).reversed().thenComparing((t1, t2) -> -1)).collect(Collectors.toList())`